# Creating xmlhttprequest in already requested page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

First of all sorry if this is really complicated to understand, but it is pretty complicated for me to explain. And also I'm very new to this Ajax thing.

Let's say I have page1.php where I have the following script:

```
function change(str) {

    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("servicetxt").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("servicetxt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","change.php?a="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

on change.php I'm making a text-field, so it appears when you call the change function on page1.php . But what if I would like to make a new request when the user is typing in this text-field (a suggestion response like this: [w3schools ajax](http://w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp))? I tried to do the following in the change.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gethint(str) {

        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?a="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
<?
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"varenummer\" onkeyup=\"gethint(this.value)\">";
echo "<p>Suggestions: <span id=\"hint\"></span></p>"; 
?>
```

But this does not work. 
There might not be a quick and simple answer to this, and if that is the case, can you then please guide me to a a good article/tutorial which can teach me how to solve this puzzle :)

Comment: im sorry i always suggest this... but have you looked up jquery, it has very nice ajax features and very easy to lean and understand.

Comment: Not yet, but I will for sure some other day. But I'm kind of in a hurry with this. Jquery seems like I have to spend some time before I will be able to use it.

Comment: yer i'm not very good with xmlhttp i like using jquery's ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no reason (unless you're planning to make a big change later) to get the text field through an AJAX call.  The field and the script that control it should be part of your main page1.php file, but the field itself should be hidden until `change()` is called, probably by clicking a button on the page.

You can hide the field by adding the attribute "hidden" and setting it to true, then adding the style "display:none" to make it work across browser's:

```
<input type="text" name="varenummer" onkeyup="gethint(this.value)" hidden=true style="display:none"/>
```

Then, on `change()`:

```
document.getElementByName("varenummer").setAttribute("hidden","false");
document.getElementByName("varenummer").style.display = "inline";
```

That way, there's no issue getting the `gethint()` script to run. Note that I just showed the HTML for your input field, not the quoted string being echoed by your php script.

### Edit

Alright, so, it's been a long time since I tried doing JS without jQuery, but I figured out what I did wrong using a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/SRs8k/2/).  There is no `.getElementByName()` function. There's a `getElementsByName()` (plural), but it doesn't work right for some reason.  So, I added an `id` parameter and set it equal to the original name parameter.  Now we can use `getElementById` and it works as expected.

```
function change() {
  document.getElementById("varenummer").setAttribute("hidden","false");
  document.getElementById("hintP").setAttribute("hidden","false");
  document.getElementById("varenummer").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("hintP").style.display = "block";
}
```

Notice that I also added similar hooks to the "Suggestions" paragraph, so it will appear when the textfield does. I don't think you need to change anything with your `gethint()` function, but I can't test that from here.

Comment: Ok I'll try this out in a sec. But now I'm just curious is it possible to do a xmlhttprequest on an ajax page like this? Or will that never be necessary?

Comment: I don't really know where to put this document.getElementByName("varenummer").setAttribute("hidden","false");
document.getElementByName("varenummer").style.display = "inline";

Currently it is in the readystate part. But that doesn't make the textbox visible.

Comment: It should be in your `change()` function, as I stated.

Comment: Yes, I've put it in the end of change() but still not visible

Comment: Can you please be more precise, I've tried to put it everywhere in the change() function, but can't get it to show the textbox.

Comment: Just edited. getElementByName() (singular) is not a real function. See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/SRs8k/2/).